# how to set focus for items in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview named `_listAvailable`. I want to refresh the listview I mean filling data `(FillOutListViewCtrl())` in listview only when items in listview doesnt have focus , what modification i need to do in the exisiting code

```
 public class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI : System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
{
            if (_refresh )
            {
                FillOutListViewCtrl();
                _refresh = false;
            }
}
```

i did following check `if (_refresh && _listAvailable.Focus()==false)`, but that will not work because i need to fill the listview when items doesn't have focus not the listview. Can anybody help me what modification i need to do? Do we have focus property for listviewitem rather than listview?

Comment: Do we have focus property for listviewitem rather than listview?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using `Listview.SelectedItems.Count`